# Pa(1,1) distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across a question saying that $X,Y$ are $Pa(1,1)$ independently distributed random variables.

I just want to ask what is the $Pa(1,1)$ distribution, since I can not find such a distribution after asking some friends and searching the internet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Pareto distribution maybe?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)